# remove punctuation for each row in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python so this may be a very basic question. I am trying to use lambda to remove punctuation for each row in a pandas dataframe. I used the following, but received an error. I am trying to avoid having convert the df into a list then append the cleaned results into new list, then convert it back to a df.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
import string

df['cleaned'] = df['old'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(c,'') for c in string.punctuation)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to iterate over the string in the dataframe, not over `string.punctuation`. You also need to build the string back up using `.join()`.

```
df['cleaned'] = df['old'].apply(lambda x:''.join([i for i in x 
                                                  if i not in string.punctuation]))
```

When lambda expressions get long like that it can be more readable to write out the function definition separately, e.g. (thanks to @AndyHayden for the optimization tips):

```
def remove_punctuation(s):
    s = ''.join([i for i in s if i not in frozenset(string.punctuation)])
    return s

df['cleaned'] = df['old'].apply(remove_punctuation)
```

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: You can accept this answer if it works for you.

Comment: One improvement here is to use set(string.punctuation) rather than string.punctuation in remove_punctuation.

Comment: Thanks, Andy. I'll add that in.

Comment: square brackets/list comprehension around the join give you another boost fwiw :)

Comment: Really! Now I've learned something.

Comment: @bernie There's a classic answer somewhere on SO about it, can't find it. IIRC ~50% faster as python needs to list anyway to calculate the length of the string.

Comment: @AndyHayden Oh I see. Thank you for the tips!

Answer (score 4):

Using a regex will most likely be faster here:

```
In [11]: RE_PUNCTUATION = '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in string.punctuation])  # perhaps this is available in the re/regex library?

In [12]: s = pd.Series(["a..b", "c<=d", "e|}f"])

In [13]: s.str.replace(RE_PUNCTUATION, "")
Out[13]:
0    ab
1    cd
2    ef
dtype: object
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer...

Comment: Similarly: `s.str.replace('[{}]'.format(string.punctuation), '')`